# For loop execution, increment confusion

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, for-loop

I don't get it why  `i` in `fillArray` method ends up  being equal to `10` even though the array score is filled only up to `index 9`.

As per my understanding `i` has to be smaller than `10`,so how can it end up being `10` at the end, it should have incremented.

I tried another loop to test if for loop executes incrementation at the end if condition is true.

In test loop `i` ends up being only 10 which makes sense but the two for loop contradict.

```
public class GoldScores {
        public static final int MAX_NUMBER_SCORES = 10;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double[] score = new double[MAX_NUMBER_SCORES];
            int numberUsed = 0;

            System.out.println("This program reads gold scores and shows");
            System.out.println("how much each differs from the average.");
            System.out.println("Enter gold scores:");
            //numberUsed = fillArray(score);
        //  showdifference(score,numberUsed);
             for(int i=1; i<11; i++){                   //Test loop
                 System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
            }
        }
        private static void showdifference(double[] score, int numberUsed) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public static int fillArray(double[] a){
            System.out.println("Enter up to " + a.length + " nonnegative numbers.");
            System.out.println("Mark the end of the list with a negative number.");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            double next = keyboard.nextDouble();
            int i = 0;
            for(i = 0;(next>=0 && i<a.length);i++){     //HELP!!!!
                a[i] = next;
                next = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }
            return i;
        }
```

Comment: What isn't working above? What output do you get? What output do you expect? Java arrays start at `0`. Index `9` is the last position with a value. Index `10` would be out of bounds.

Comment: everything works but i dont get why "i" in for loop in fillArray ends up being 10 even though 10 < a.length is wrong.----- doesn't make sense
on the other hand for loop in main method "i" ends up only being 10  which is 10< 11 so it seems right and makes sense

Comment: Start over... 10 == a.length, and the test was `<`. `9 < a.length` add one. What value do you have? Your second example counts from 1 to 11 (not 0 to 10), and you aren't looking at the value after the loop (it would be one higher).

Answer (score 6):

You must understand exactly how the `for` loop works to understand what is going on, and why `i` is `10` after the `for` loop in `fillArray`.

1. Perform initialization, before the first semicolon.
2. Test the condition in between the first and second semicolons.  If the condition is `false`, break out of the loop.
3. Execute the body of the loop.
4. Perform the statement after the second semicolon (the increment).
5. Go back to Step 2.

In the last iteration of the `i` `for` loop, `i` is `9`, and index `9` is assigned in the array, step 3.  Step 4 performs the increment, and `i` is now `10`.  *Then* the condition is tested, which is `false`, and the loop is exited.  `i` is now `10`.

However, in your `main` `for` loop, you print the value in the body instead of examining the looping variable afterwards.  The last iteration is when `i` is `10`, because the condition is different: `i < 11`.  If you were to print `i` after that `for` loop, you'll see it's `11`.

Comment: okay thanks, I get it but its not sitting in my head probably need more practice

Answer (score 0):

in For loop, increment occurs after testing loop condition, not before. So in last iteration when your condition is checked, I is already equal to 10 and that is exactly what is being returned. Consider this, if your I would still be 9 in last iteration, your condition would still be true which would mean one more execution in loop.

Answer (score 0):

While others have already explained in detail , to eliminate confusion you could modify your code to something like :

```
        double next = keyboard.nextDouble();
        int i = 0;
        int current_i = i;
        for( i = 0; ( next >= 0 && i < a.length ); i++ )
        {
            current_i = i;
            a[i] = next;
            next = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
        return current_i;
```

instead of

```
        double next = keyboard.nextDouble();
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0;(next>=0 && i<a.length);i++){     //HELP!!!!
            a[i] = next;
            next = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
        return i;
```